# Invalid requests in my browser when two users are logged in

Tags: internet, browser

I noticed that when I'm logged in to multiple users (namely two) I have problems with making requests in my browser. I frequently get an error that the page cannot be loaded (like there was no internet connection) and I need to refresh for a couple of times. The same is for `git push` command. I'm pretty sure that the internet connection is stable, because I still can have a call via Google Meet and there aren't any problems occuring with that. From my internet provider side everything works as well. The problem occurs both on the wired connection and with wi-fi.

After restart of the system or at least logging out the other user it's getting better but I think it should still work when I'm logged in to more than one user accounts at the same time.

My Ubuntu version is 20.04.5 LTS and `uname -r` returns `5.15.0-52-generic`

Comment: How and to what are you logging in as 2 users at once?

Comment: I have one user for professional purposes and one for personal. I switch user after finishing my work not to close all windows which I need for the next day.

Comment: Not what I asked and please ask what I did ask it is critical to offering any help.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood. I'm just logging to one user after starting my system, then I switch user (with first user's session still working) and log into another user.